# When does Ramadan start exactly?

Tags: ramadan

If ramadan is on April 2, does ramadan start at 12am April 2? Or does ramadan start April 1 after sunset (after maghrib)? Or does ramadan start fajr time April 2?

Comment: Ramadan starts at Maghrib and ends at Maghrib.

Comment: The Islamic days and months always start at Maghrib so once the hilal (crescent moon) was seen -at this time- anything related to Ramadan starts including taraweeh prayer and fast etc.. The only ambiguity is whether you follow  a local moon (sighting) or a global (moon sighting).

Answer (score 1):

Ramadan starts at sunset since the day starts at sunset. That is why is tarawih begins on the same night that the crescent of ramadan is sighted and stops when the crescent of shawwal is sighted.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

First of all, regarding **"Ramazan"**.

Do not be saying, **"Ramazan starts"**, **"Ramazan ends"**, **"This is Ramazan"**, **"Ramazan is gone"** or **"Ramazan has come"**, for **"Ramazan"** is a Name from the Names of Allah AZWJ (Mighty and Majestic). **"It"** neither comes nor does **"It"** go. But rather it is the transient (thing) which comes and goes.

You should be saying, **"Shahri Ramazan (Month of Ramadan)"**, for the **"Shahri (Month)"** is an adverb to the Name, and the Name is a Name of Allah AZWJ (Mighty and Majestic).

<sup>source: [Al Kafi – V 4 – The Book of Fasts Ch 4 H 2](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol4/Al%20Kafi%20V4%20-%20The%20Book%20of%20Fasts%20(1).pdf)</sup>

**Now regarding your question**

`When does Shahri Ramazan start exactly?`

According to Imam Hussain, It is the crescent of the month. So whenever you see the new moon, so Fast (meaning from next Fajr, meaning Shahri Ramazan has started), and when you see it (again), so break the Fasting (meaning from next Fajr you will not be fasting, meaning Shahri Ramazan has ended)

> [image]
>
> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (asws), said, ‘He (asws) was
> asked about the crescent, so he (asws) said: ‘It is the crescent of
> the month. So whenever you see the new moon, so Fast, and when you see
> it (again), so break the Fasting’.
>
> <sup>source: [Al Kafi – V 4 – The Book of Fasts Ch 6 H 1](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol4/Al%20Kafi%20V4%20-%20The%20Book%20of%20Fasts%20(1).pdf)</sup>